# not able to install Groovy in windows 10

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am trying to install Groovy on windows 10. I have Java 17.0.4.1 installed and trying to install groovy 4.0.5 & here is the link (https://groovy.jfrog.io/ui/native/dist-release-local/groovy-windows-installer/groovy-4.0.5/) after installation I opened command prompt typed "groovy --version" its returning empty.

[image]

I have looked at the Environment variable under System variables GROOVY_HOME is created and also the Path.
[image]

this image is from the Path:

[image]

I am not able to understand why the "groovy --version" is giving empty. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: goto `%groovy_home%/bin`, run `set DEBUG=true`, and try to run `groovy.bat`. check console logs...

Comment: it's not working

Comment: How exactly it's not working? Empty screen?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue today !!
Below are my findings and solved my problem if these can help

My JDK installed in system : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`
I set Environment Variable : JAVA_HOME and value : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`
I installed using installer - groovy-4.0.7.msi
I set Environment Variable : GROOVY_HOME and value : %GROOVY_HOME%bin

groovy -version
Groovy Version: 4.0.7 JVM: 1.8.0_201 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10

Apology I am not able to share screen shot. Hope this might help.

Comment: I do not get what exactly the solution is. Please [edit] according to [answer].